# Android Bar code scanner to scan multiple bar code in one shot

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-support-library, barcode-scanner

I'm Using Zbar for bar code scanning and it is working perfect.
Now what I want is to Scan N numbers of bar code at once or minimum five and show its data in a list.I'have achieved this with button click.
but I want it to scan bar code continuously.
**for example :** when we scan any bar code it will scan and saves the data in array, then again it will start to scan bar code.

> Following code I'm using to scan One Bar code.

```
public class CameraTestActivity extends Activity
{
private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;
private Handler autoFocusHandler;
TextView scanText;
Button scanButton;
ImageScanner scanner;
private boolean barcodeScanned = false;
private boolean previewing = true;
static {
System.loadLibrary("iconv");
} 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
autoFocusHandler = new Handler();
mCamera = getCameraInstance();
/* Instance barcode scanner */
scanner = new ImageScanner();
scanner.setConfig(0, Config.X_DENSITY, 3);
scanner.setConfig(0, Config.Y_DENSITY, 3);
mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera, previewCb, autoFocusCB);
FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
preview.addView(mPreview);
scanText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scanText);
scanButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ScanButton);
if (barcodeScanned) {
barcodeScanned = false;
scanText.setText("Scanning...");
mCamera.setPreviewCallback(previewCb);
mCamera.startPreview();
previewing = true;
mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCB);
}
scanButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
if (barcodeScanned) {
barcodeScanned = false;
scanText.setText("Scanning...");
mCamera.setPreviewCallback(previewCb);
mCamera.startPreview();
previewing = true;
mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCB);
}
}
});
}
public void onPause() {
super.onPause();
releaseCamera();
}
/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
Camera c = null;
try {
c = Camera.open();
} catch (Exception e){
}
return c;
}
private void releaseCamera() {
if (mCamera != null) {
previewing = false;
mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
mCamera.release();
mCamera = null;
}
}
private Runnable doAutoFocus = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
if (previewing)
mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCB);
}
};
PreviewCallback previewCb = new PreviewCallback() {
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize(); 
Image barcode = new Image(size.width, size.height, "Y800");
barcode.setData(data);
int result = scanner.scanImage(barcode);
if (result != 0) {
previewing = false;
mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
mCamera.stopPreview();
SymbolSet syms = scanner.getResults();
for (Symbol sym : syms) {
scanText.setText("barcode result " + sym.getData());
scanButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
barcodeScanned = true;
}
}
}
};
// Mimic continuous auto-focusing
AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCB = new AutoFocusCallback() {
public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
autoFocusHandler.postDelayed(doAutoFocus, 1000);
}
};
}
```

Comment: see this https://github.com/zxing/zxing

Comment: @Lakhan Thank you :) But I don't wanna use zxing.